# Access audio buffer of an AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

Hope this question makes some sense, I'm completely lost....
In my proto-app I'm recording micro input and saving it, and so far no problems at all.

I now need to access the buffer while I'm recording it in order to pass chunks of data to another class (written in C, not by me) that will do some analysis.

I spent the whole day browsing and reading, and looks like I need use Audio Queues in order to access the buffer.
The problem is that the syntax is C, and I don't understand it at all :)

So my questions are:

1) Is there any other way to achieve what I'm looking for? I don't need in-depth explanation, just some hints and I will browse my way through :)  I'm asking because I'm not 100% sure that Audio Queues are the only way to go

2) Any good tutorial or example about Audio Queues? The [aurioTouch tutorial by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011369-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) wasn't very useful (again, I don't know C). I could bypass my problems in C by following a good tutorial that a noob like me can understand

Thanks a lot, and for any help you could offer.

Comment: The low level audio APIs and raw buffer formars are all C based, so it would be best for you to learn a little about C and C data types, as C is a proper and very useful subset of Objective C, especially for any audio work.

Comment: I knew absolutely nothing about Core Audio and only knew C and was able to work out building and tearing down audio graphs with a bit of practice. If you're at all serious about audio on iOS or OSX then [Chris A's book][amazon] is indispensable. [amazon]:http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Core-Audio-Hands-On-Programming/dp/0321636848

Comment: thx @nick I've also found that book and read some samples/extracts from the web, but again, my problem is that I'm not into C at all. I will probably ask some help because this is getting probably too hardcore for me :)

Comment: By the way, what class you need to pass the data to? What kind of analysis it does? Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.
You can use code written by other people like:

[Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) - pretty straightforward. (but there are some bugs, at least in older version I used ~ 6 months ago. Something with mono and stereo.)

[Momu](http://momu.stanford.edu/toolkit/) - quite a good thing in C++ (you need to use .mm extension for you files)

Those will save you time if you want some low level audio programming. Some basic skills in C still required though. Check out [this guy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ps8jOj7diA0&list=SP9D558D49CA734A02). His explanations and enthusiasm are excellent.

With all mentioned above you can be ready in a 1-2 days of work carrying away good skills in C.

**EDIT**

Basically, everywhere you work with low-level audio you deal with a C array of numbers (represented like `float *audioBuffer;`) called audio samples. You cycle through it in a loop, do some operations, copy it, send somewhere, analyze.

To copy it you have to allocate space for it. Actual byte size of the buffer can be calculated like this: numberOfSamples*sizeof(type).

Comment: I would also recommend iOS **Accelerate.framework**, especially its **vDSP** part for working with low level audio. Use it instead of loops when performing math operations on your audio buffers (vectors) - it works much faster.

Comment: thx @krafter I'm now having a look to Novocaine. Any good docs or tutorial? From the code I'm reading in the examples it's still unclear how to access data in the incoming buffer

Comment: On the github page in **"Getting Audio"** section there is the code to get audio from mic. That block is invoked every few milliseconds bringing new audio data in **float *newAudio** variable.